# Html, duvida sobre compatibilidade com o Internet Explorer

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

Eu não sei porque mas o meu site fica quebrado no Internet Explorer e Microsoft Edge. Ja no Firefox, Google Chrome e Opera Web o site fica normal. As unicas partes do site que ficam quebradas são o Aside e o Footer

Eu vi um post aqui no stack overflow em que um cara falava sobre uma tag "@supports" e "-ms-".

No meu script eu uso o sistema de Grid.

Eu sou bem iniciante, só aprendi o basico de CSS e HTML.

Esse é a parte de cima do meu script que contém os códigos de Grid.

```
body{
    padding: 0; margin: 0;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}
#main {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-areas: "header header" "nav nav" "content aside" "footer footer";
}
.mainHeader {grid-area: header; background: #1A1A1A; height: 100px;}
.logo {margin: 12px 10px 10px 98px;}
.mainNav {grid-area: nav; background: #333333; margin-top: -19px;}
.mainContent {grid-area: content; background: #f8f8f8; margin-left: 200px; margin-right: 200px; width: 550px; margin-bottom: -570px; margin-top: 23px; height: 1000px;}
.mainAside {grid-area: aside; background: #f8f8f8; margin-right: 200px; margin-left: -200px; width: 407px; margin-bottom: -570px; margin-top: 23px; height: 1000px;}
.mainFooter {grid-area: footer; background: #1A1A1A; height: 19px;}
```

**No Internet Explorer:**
[image: No Internet Explorer]

**No Internet Explorer: Footer**
.
.
[image: 2]

**Nos outros navegadores**:
[image: Nos outros navegadores]

Comment: Como vc pode ver aqui apenas o IE11 suporta parcialmente o Grid https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-grid e o ideal seria sim usar o prefixo -ms- que é o vendo prefix dos browsers da microsoft, apesar no Edge aceitar alguns prefixos webkit tb... o @suports é para vc construir uma regra de css caso o browser de suporte, se ele não der vc pode usar o flex box por exemplo. Ou então algum polyfill de grid ou até o Normalize para tratar esses casos. Isso pode te interessar https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2017/11/css-grid-supporting-browsers-without-grid/

Comment: @hugocsl Como eu coloco o -ms- no meu script? Eu dei uma pesquisada no google e não achei nada.

Comment: Basta colocar todo o seu CSS nesse AutoPrefixer por exemplo... https://autoprefixer.github.io/ Ai vc vai ver que ele vai colocar todos os prefixos -ms- onde precisar. Porém nem todas as propriedades do grid funcionam no IE, e só funciona no IE 11, do 10 para baixo só com Normalizer ou Polifill

Comment: Internet explorer só server pra instalar baixar e instalar outro navegador. #pas

Comment: @WallaceMaxters Realmente lol.

Answer (score 1):

Não tem *polyfill* ou *autoprefixer* que vá resolver 100% o caso disto, `display: grid` é algo super novo, claro que talvez para IE11:

```
#main {
    display: grid;
    display: -ms-grid;
    grid-template-areas: "header header" "nav nav" "content aside" "footer footer";
}
```

Resolva parcialmente, mas para `grid-template-areas` não vai ter nada para IE, o que você vai ter que fazer é usar:

```
grid-template-rows: ...;
grid-template-columns: ...;

-ms-grid-template-rows: ...;
-ms-grid-template-columns: ...;
```

E provavelmente irá arrumar boa parte, mas não há garantias, o suporte é parcial, e se quiser algo a mais é provavel que não vai dar certo, ou que vá dá muito trabalho.

Resumindo, já era possivel fazer layouts sem o uso de grids ou flex, por favor não entenda como critica, mas como orientação, aprender `grids` sem aprender o básico do CSS e HTML, como:

- CSS 1
- CSS 2.0
- CSS 2.1
- DOCTYPE

E querer partir para usar grid, flexbox e afins é como aprender a dirigir sem ter aprendido a andar (perdoem-me pela analogia forçada), não tem meio-termo, ou você aprende o básico ou você vai sofrer quando não deveria.

Sinceramente eu não vejo o porque dessa fixação exagerada do povo com FLEX e GRID **em coisas básicas**, sério dá pra simplificar tudo, até mesmo bootstrap3 que ainda é o mais usado das "4" versões não usa nada disso.

Entenda que IE nunca mais vai receber novidades, o novo IE é nomeado Edge, ele é a versão atualizada do IE, ele é o IE, só que renomearam, tem um novo motor e tem suporte a maior parte das tecnolgias, IE9, 10 e 11 são navegadores antigos, em uma lógica de versionamento não tem sentido adicionar novas coisas, sendo que temos o IE 12 (agora chamado de MSEdge) e até o 16 (até a data de 9/8/2018), se eles fizessem isso quebrariam todo o sentido de versionar, aliais eu tenho um computador antigo com Firefox 3.6, mas nunca esperei que ele suportasse CSS3 só porque esta instalado lá.

> **Nota** `@supports` é algo também novo e é somente suportado pelo MS Edge 12, ou seja nem funciona no IE11 para que você pudesse criar um fallback.

O problema sinceramente esta ligado a artigos, videos e as novidades e como elas são transmitidas para quem esta aprendendo agora, eles falam de CSS3 como se CSS2 não funcionasse mais, sendo que que CSS3 é:

```
CSS1 + CSS2 + Novidades = CSS3
```

Eu vejo muitas respostas aqui no site que ainda incentivam o erro de entendimento, não tenho como ir contra isto, é complicado explicar para um por um que suas resposta estão ensinando errado ou levando ao erro.

Então aprender CSS1 e CSS2 é aprender o CSS3, pois eles fazem parte do CSS3 ainda, nada foi substituído, só foi acrescentado.

Se quer suporte para navegadores antigos, então faça como tal e uso o que tem suporte conforme o navegador, o MDN é um bom site para ajudar, também existe o caniuse:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS
- https://caniuse.com

Existem outros sites, mas não recomendo, ou por **não serem boas fontes**, ou por serem leituras técnicas demais para quem esta começando.

---

> Aliais se apresentar a parte HTML eu posso até sugerir como fazer isso **sem usar GRID** e que vai funcionar bem até no IE8.

Comment: Consegui resolver meu problema com o -ms-grid e grid-template-columns, e ficou perfeitamente do jeito que eu queria, talvez seja porque não tem muitos elementos na minha pagina.

Comment: @unknn que bom que deu certo, fico feliz, ainda sim não deixe de estudar o CSS1, 2 antes de usar coisas assim :)

Comment: O meu professor tinha me ensinado sobre 'col' col1-col12. Ate então era a unica forma que eu conhecia, e eu mal entendi como funcionava. Já o grid eu aprendi na hora. Mas eu tou indo pelo basico mesmo, estudando primeiro o CSS.

Comment: @unknn isso ai são maneira de fazer e vc mesmo escrever, geralmente em frameworks feitos em CSS, como bootstrap ou uikit, seguem esse padrão, não tem ligação com o CSS direto, é só uma maneira de vc organizar algo, aliais, uma pergunta, teu professor lhes ensinaram os principios básicos do CSS? Como seletores, comportamento do DOCTYPE, a diferença de inline, block e inline-block?

Comment: Não, eu fiz um curso pra iniciante, e no final do curso ele ensinou a fazer um site. O resto eu aprendi por mim mesmo, pesquisando no youtube, e por sinal existe muito conteudo bom gratuito.

Comment: @unknn que bom que esta se esforçando, infelizmente eu meio que discordo de você, muitas video aulas que parecem boas, só parecem mesmo, tem muita gente ensinando errado ou ensinando muito a frente pulando os principios básicos. Mas é a vida, já aceito como estão as coisas. Boa sorte :)