# CSS Grid Layout - Compatibilidade dos browsers

Tags: css, grid, grid-layout

Com relação à desenvolvimento Web, tenho estudado **CSS grid layout** usando, principalmente, vídeos. Alguns são um pouco mais antigos e instruem a não usar essa especificação em produção, pois o site vai quebrar. 

Minha dúvida é: até que ponto isso continua sendo verdade nos dias de hoje? Ou Grid Layout do CSS já é algo mais consolidado atualmente, e vários browsers já são compatíveis?

Comment: Por favor Massau leia isto: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/321333/3635 - Entenda que trabalho com CSS desde que IE6 era o navegador mais usado e Firefox ainda estava na versão 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bom, me baseando neste [link](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-grid) do site **can i use**, ele tem total suporte de praticamente todos os principais navegadores web hoje em dia, com exceção do **IE** versão **11** que é necessário utilizar o prefixo `-ms-` e o **Opera Mini** que não possui suporte algum à este sistema de grid específico.